# Inline(html) onclick function doesn't work as expected on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a div html tag which has a "onclick" function. On a mobile device, to be specific web browser(blackberry work) on iPhone 12, I have to click on a particular div several times to invoke onclick function. I have looked into similar problems on StackOverflow but all of them talk about using $('#div').on('click touchstart'). In my case, I cannot do that. I'm looking for alternative solution that works for both desktop and mobile page consistently without screwing the user experience.

```js
function changeText(){
$("#text-tag").text('Text replaced');
}
```

```css
.div-button {
border-radius:50%;
border: 1px solid blue;
background: blue;
width:30px;
height:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4> Click on the blue circle to do magic!</h4>
<div class="div-button" onclick="changeText()">
</div>
<p id="text-tag">This text will be replaced</p>
```

Comment: *In my case, I cannot do that...*, could you elaborate why?

Comment: `all of them talk about using $('#div').on('click touchstart'). In my case, I cannot do that` Why? It's by far the better approach here. Also, are you sure that the button is failing to work, or is it instead that the hit area for it is too small and it's not being triggered?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Because I don't have access to the html tag where this inline function is defined, the tag is dynamically generated on the dom once the page loads. If I use $('#div').on('click touchstart') then I will have two onclick functions one inline, one in the script.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan ah interesting! How did I not think of the hit area? I was zooming into the page on my mobile that led me to think that the div is big enough to click. It may solve my problem but I will have to try. Thank you though.